# Variable is out of scope

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to iterate over a few input fields and add then to the `order` array.

Once the `each()` has finished I then want to call the `addTask` function with the `order` array. but.

When I run through the console it jumps into the `addTask(order)` and only gets 1 result

When I move the `order` array out of the function it doesnt know it is there. 
What would be advisable to get this back into scope when the `each()` has finished.

```
// Start adding orders to display
$("#btn-new-line").on('click', function(){
 $("input:text").each(function(index, element){
     var elem = $(element);
     var order = [] ;
     order.push(elem.val()+ " ");
});
addTask(order); //* unresolved variable *
});
```

Comment: You're re-declaring the variable each time by calling `var order = [];`, which is wiping out your results.

Comment: declare the variable before `.on` then set the value inside of it

Comment: Move the declaration of `var order=[];` to before the `.each()`

Comment: Thanks guys works lovely now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your "order" variable every loop through.

```
// Start adding orders to display
$("#btn-new-line").on('click', function(){
   var order = [] ;
   $("input:text").each(function(index, element){
       var elem = $(element);
       order.push(elem.val()+ " ");
   });
   addTask(order); //* unresolved variable *
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it like this:

```
$("#btn-new-line").on('click', function(){
   var order = [] ;
    $("input:text").each(function(index, element){
        var elem = $(element);
        order.push(elem.val()+ " ");
    });
    addTask(order); //* unresolved variable *
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Start adding orders to display
var order = [] ;
$("#btn-new-line").on('click', function(){
 $("input:text").each(function(index, element){
     var elem = $(element);
     order.push(elem.val()+ " ");
});
addTask(order); //* unresolved variable *
});
```

Comment: This will work, but declares the variable in the global space, which is to be avoided if possible.

Comment: if it's nested in some other function (which i don't know) it's not in global scope ;-)

Comment: True, but irrelevant since you don't know, and the variable can (and probably should) be declared inside the click handler anyway.

Comment: True, but irrelevant because you don't know what he wants to do with the collected data afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `order` variable in your click handler:

```
// Start adding orders to display
$("#btn-new-line").on('click', function(){
   var order = [] ;

   $("input:text").each(function(index, element){
     var elem = $(element);
     order.push(elem.val()+ " ");   // order still accessible through the enclosing function.
   });
  addTask(order);
```

});

Answer (score -3):

Order scope is limited to callback as you are creating inside it and not extending it.

```
$("#btn-new-line").on('click', function () {
    $("input:text").each(function (index, element) {
        var elem = $(element);
        var order = [];
        order.push(elem.val() + " ");
        addTask(order); //* unresolved variable *
    });
});
```

Comment: Read the other answers and you'll see

Comment: Read the question again `Once the each() has finished I then want to call the addTask function with the order array`